# Give php code an ID to target with CSS

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm using this code to add a phone number to our Storefront themed wordpress header, however, I'd like it to be hidden on mobile devices. How do I give the element an ID so that I can target it with CSS to hide on mobile?

```
add_action( 'storefront_header', 'jk_storefront_header_content', 40 );
    function jk_storefront_header_content() { ?>
         <div style="clear: both; text-align: right;">
               Have questions about our products? <em>Give us a call:</em> <strong>0800 123 456</strong>
         </div>
     <?php
 }
```

I've tried many things but haven't managed to do it.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Emily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the div an Id

```
<div style="clear: both; text-align: right;" id="contact_phone">
Have questions about our products? <em>Give us a call:</em> 
<strong>0800 123 456</strong>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add an `id` or even better `class` attribute to the `<div />`

```
<div style="clear: both; text-align: right;" class="hidden-mobile">
```